# Silverlight rich text box - copy and paste html

Tags: html, xaml, silverlight-4.0, richtextbox, copy-paste

I am using silverlight rich text box for capturing description for certain entities. One of the requirement is that user should be able to copy data from web pages (Internet) and paste inside the rich text box.

Rich text box in Silverlight uses XAML to format the data and there is no built in feature to convert HTML to XAML.

Please let me know if there is any such utility/control. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://blog.spencen.com/2008/01/19/html-to-flowdocument-converter.aspx) a good place to start. The converter mentioned there is not bullet proof but for simple conversions it's not bad.

It's a WPF utility, but IIRC, there was a source code for it (can't access the site right now), and I don't think there should be too much trouble to convert it to Silverlight.

Comment: +1 for your reply. I will check if I can modify and use the code in Silverlight.